# Horspool list all instances of string

Tags: c, string, search, pattern-matching, string-search

I'm trying to use the Horspool algorithm to list all instances of a pattern in a string.
My string is very long, north of 3 million characters.

On windows, my code only finds the first ~230 instances of the word "the". On linux, my code finds the first ~580 instances of the word "the". In both cases, the program just stalls after it reaches that count. No seg fault, no termination, it just stalls. There should be 2300+ instances of the word "the"

My logic is as follows:

1. Use horspool algorithm to find first instance of pattern in overall string
2. Use horspool algorithm to find next instance of pattern in (overall string + previous horspool index)
3. And so on until the index of the search is greater than the length of the string.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void shifttable(char p[], int t[], int asciiSize)
{
    int i,j,m;
    m=strlen(p);
    for(i=0;i<asciiSize;i++)
        t[i]=m;
    for(j=0;j<m-1;j++)
        t[p[j]]=m-1-j;
}
int horspool(char src[],char p[], int table[])
{
    int i,j,k,m,n;
    n=strlen(src);
    m=strlen(p);
    i=m-1;
    while(i<n)
    {
        k=0;
        while((k<m)&&(p[m-1-k]==src[i-k]))
            k++;
        if(k==m)
            return(i-m+1);
        else
            i+=table[src[i]];
    }
    return -1;
}
int main()
{
    //Get pattern
    char p[100];
    printf("Enter the pattern: ");
    gets(p);
    int patternLength = strlen(p);
    printf("Length: %d\n", patternLength);

    //Get fileData
    char * src = 0;
    long length;
    FILE * fp = fopen("data_5.txt", "r");

    if (fp)
    {
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell (fp);
        fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        src = malloc(length);
        if (src)
        {
            fread (src, 1, length, fp);
        }
        fclose (fp);
    }

    //ShiftTable
    int asciiSize = 128;
    int * table = malloc(sizeof(int) * asciiSize);
    shifttable(p, table, asciiSize);
    int pos = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int numFound = 0;
    while (count < length) {
        printf("src:%d, count:%d\n", src, count);
        pos=horspool(src+count,p, table);
        if(pos>=0) {
            count = count + pos + patternLength;
            numFound++;
            printf("#:%d, Position %d\n",numFound, count+1);
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe your input contains non-ascii characters.

Comment: @rici I am able to print the whole input as a string before the while loop horspool search. Would that be allowed if there were non-ascii characters? Additionally, it does not throw an error, only stalls.

Comment: Yes, it would be permitted. It doesn't "stall"; it goes into an endless loop. The simplest explanation is that you are reading a negative value when you index `table` with an out-of-range index.

Comment: Don't assume C will protect you by detecting error conditions and producing helpful error messages. That is not the C way.

Comment: Perfect. It was an infinite loop. The issue was that in the shifttable, a character would return 0, and so the i value in the loop would not increment. Thank you @rici

Comment: OT:   The function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from the latest versions of the C language.  Suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum, use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.  The posted code causes the compiler to output LOTS of warning messages, of which several need to be corrected.  Also, When calling C library functions, like `fopen()` and `fread()` always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not an `int`